# Reload config of xmobar

Tags: arch-linux, xmonad

I'm happily using [xmobar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmobar) with [xmonad](https://xmonad.org/) as my window manager.

When changing the configuration of xmonad, I use <kbd>mod</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> to make the new configuration effective.

This works fine for xmonad but I noticed that xmobar does not reload its configuration.

How can I reload xmobar's configuration?

---

My current configuration in `xmonad.hs` is

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import System.IO

main = do

  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"

  xmonad $ defaultConfig {
          manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
        , layoutHook = avoidStruts  $
                      layoutHook defaultConfig
        -- Without this, the xmonad pane would hide xmobar
        -- From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288037/xmobar-does-not-appear-on-top-of-window-stack-when-xmonad-starts/303242
        , handleEventHook = handleEventHook defaultConfig <+> docksEventHook
        , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
                        { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
                        , ppTitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 50
                        }
        , modMask = mod4Mask     -- Rebind Mod to the Windows key
        , terminal = "urxvt"
        , borderWidth = 1
        , normalBorderColor = "#edf9ee"
        , focusedBorderColor = "dark green"
        , focusFollowsMouse = False
        } `additionalKeys`
        [
          -- Toggle xmobar using mod + b
          ((mod4Mask, xK_b), sendMessage ToggleStruts)
          -- Make a screenshot of the whole screen with the print key
        , ((0, xK_Print), spawn "import -window root screenshot_$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S).png")
        ]
```

This is the configuration from `.xmobarrc`:

```
-- Configure the status bar for xmonad: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmobar
Config { font = "-*-Fixed-Bold-R-Normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
        , borderColor = "black"
        , border = TopB
        , bgColor = "blue"
        , fgColor = "grey"
        , position = TopW L 100
        , commands = [ Run MultiCpu ["-t","Cpu: <total0> <total1> <total2> <total3>","-L","30","-H","60","-h","#FFB6B0","-l","#CEFFAC","-n","#FFFFCC","-w","3"] 10
                     , Run Memory ["-t","Mem: <usedratio>%"] 10
                     , Run Battery ["-t","Bat: <left>% / <timeleft>","-L","30","-H","60","-h","green","-n","yellow","-l","red"] 10
                     , Run Com "uname" ["-s","-r"] "" 36000
                     , Run Date "%a %F %H:%M" "date" 10
                     ]
        , sepChar = "%"
        , alignSep = "}{"
        , template = "%multicpu% | %memory% | %battery%}{<fc=#ee9a00>%date%</fc> | %uname% "
        , hideOnStart = False
        , persistent = True
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have xmonad set up to start xmobar like this:

```
main = xmonad <=< xmobar $ defaultConfig
        { terminal = "xterm"
        -- , modMask = mod4Mask
        , borderWidth = 3
        } `additionalKeys`
        [ ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_z), spawn "xscreensaver-command -l")
        ]
```

then you simply need to reload xmonad using `mod-q` to reload xmonad and xmobar.

Answer (score 1):

Since xmonad will show a restarted xmobar just fine, I use

```
killall xmobar; xmobar &
```

in my terminal to make the changes in `.xmobarrc` effective.

Comment: This will make xmobar go away when you quit terminal.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have xmonad configured to show xmobar at a specific monitor with a dual monitor setup.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to xmonad, I changed my Mod+q (refresh xmonad) from

```
xmonad --recompile; xmonad --restart
```

to

```
xmonad --recompile; killall xmobar; xmonad --restart
```

it works just fine when trying to change the bar size and Mod+q.